In Maui, how to get USB disconnection event on Windows?
In WindowsForms I would use this method to detect every device connection change, but how can I do something similar in MAUI for Windows? (Ideally I only need to detect if any USB is disconnected)
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)



In Maui, how to get USB disconnection event on Windows?

Since you are targeting on Windows, you can use the Windows.Devices.Enumeration namespace to enumerate devices. It has a DeviceWatcher class which will trigger events when devices are added, removed, or updated.
